PIC32MZ not detecting when quadrature encoder is turned
My Problem
I'm trying to interface a quadrature encoder, this one, to a PIC32MZ. I made a simple test to check the functionality of the encoder, but I cannot get the Input Capture peripheral of the PIC32 to detect the rising edges of encoder channel A or B pwm signals.
I'm using the Curiosity PIC32MZ EF 2.0 Development Board with MPLABX IDE and Harmony library.
Because I'm using MPLABX IDE with Harmony, assume all PIC32 periphals are configured correctly.

I have 2 Input Capture Peripherals, ICAP7 and ICAP8, connected to channels A and B of the encoder.
For each of the Input Captures the following settings have been applied:

Simple Capture Event mode every rising edge
16 bit timer resource capture
Enable Capture Interrupt

The test I have tried to implement is depicted in the following diagram:

Below is the code written on the PIC32 to implement the test:
ICAP7_Initialize(); //From library
ICAP7_Enable(); //From library

//Set LED Pin to Output
GPIO_RJ7_OutputEnable(); //From library

//Call encoderTurned on inturrupt
ICAP7_CallbackRegister(encoderTurned, (uintptr_t)NULL); //From Library

encoderTurned function:
void encoderTurned(uintptr_t context){

    GPIO_RJ7_Toggle(); //From library
}


Did you use the "suggested filter circuit" (page 2 of datasheet)?

@Antonio51 Yes I did. I tried both with and without the filter circuit

1, Verify e.g. with a DVM that the encoder does provided high and low signals

@Hannu. I verified with an oscilloscope that high and low signals are generated when the encoder is turned.

Use e.g. a push button or a switch of some kind to make sure to detect it being open or closed with correct port settings and related software in the PIC. The encoder does nothing special beyond that, just repeatedly opens and closes "the switch". The very special thing is that you have A and B "switches" timed with 90 degree "pulse-phase" (electrical degrees) between them.
